# Ruby no Method Error

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I'm just learning Ruby and having a hard time with this error, I read some posts which all said to define the method like this...

```
def self.methodname
```

I did this but to no avail. here is my code Hopefully it's a simple thing I'm missing. Thanks for the help.

```
class Cannibals
@VEGANS = 3
@CANNIBALS = 3
@VEGAN_ID = 0
@CANNIBAL_ID = 1
@EMPTY_ID = 2
@CROSSED_ID = 0
@SHORE_ID = 1

@vegansCrossed=0
@cannibalsCrossed=0
@vegansLeft = @VEGANS
@cannibalsLeft = @CANNIBALS
@boat = [@EMPTY_ID,@EMPTY_ID]
@boatLocation = @SHORE_ID


#/* take an integer as argument1, 
# * 0- load 2 cannibals
# * 1- load 2 vegans
# * 2- load one of each.
# * 3- load 1 cannibal
# * 4- load 1 vegan 
# * argument 2 is destionation
# * 0- crossed
# * 1- shore*/
def self.populateBoat (choice,destination )
    message = "Invalid arguments delivered"
    boatDestination

    validChoice = false
case choice
    when 0
        validChoice = true
        if destination == @CROSSED_ID
            @cannibalsLeft -= 2
        elsif destination == @SHORE_ID 
            @cannibalsCrossed -=2
        end
        @boat[0] = @CANNIBAL_ID
        @boat[1] = @CANNIBAL_ID

    when 1
        validChoice = true
        if destination == @CROSSED_ID
            @vegansLeft -= 2
            elsif destination == @SHORE_ID 
            @vegansCrossed -= 2
        end
        @boat[0] = @VEGAN_ID
        @boat[1] = @VEGAN_ID
    when 2
        validChoice = true
        if destination == @CROSSED_ID
            --@vegansLeft
            --@cannibalsLeft
            elsif destination == @SHORE_ID
                --@vegansCrossed
                --@cannibalsCrossed
        end
        @boat[0] = @VEGAN_ID
        @boat[1] = @CANNIBAL_ID
    when 3
        validChoice = true
        if destination == @CROSSED_ID
            --@cannibalsLeft
            elsif destination == @SHORE_ID 

            --@cannibalsCrossed
        end

        @boat[0] = @CANNIBAL_ID
        @boat[1] = @EMPTY_ID
    when 4
        validChoice = true
        if destination == @CROSSED_ID 

            --@vegansLeft
            elsif destination == @SHORE_ID 

            --@vegansCrossed
        end

        @boat[0] = @VEGAN_ID
        @boat[1] = @EMPTY_ID
    else
        message = "Invalid choice"
end
    if validChoice 

        if destination == @SHORE_ID 
            boatDestination = "the starting point."
            elsif destination == @CROSSED_ID 
                boatDestination = "the ending point."
        else
            boatDestination = "a place unknown, they're off track."
        message = @getBoatOccupants   + "heading to " + boatDestination +"\n"
        end
    end
    return message

end
#/*Unload the boat, takes an integer for an argument
# * 0- unload crossed
# * 1- unload at shore */
def unloadBoat (where) 


    #create message
    String message = "They sunk the boat. \n"
    if @boatLocation == @SHORE_ID 
        message = "Boat unloaded at ending point. \n"

        elsif @boatLocation == @CROSSED_ID 
            message = "Boat unloaded at starting point. \n"
    end

    i = 0
    if where == @CROSSED_ID 
        for i in 0..1 
            if @boat[i] == @VEGAN_ID 
                @vegansCrossed += 1
            end
            if @boat[i] == @CANNIBAL_ID 
                @cannibalsCrossed += 1
            end
            @boat[i]=@EMPTY_ID
        end
        @boatLocation = @CROSSED_ID
        elsif where == @SHORE_ID        

            for i in 0..1 

                if @boat[i] == @VEGAN_ID 

                    @vegansLeft += 1
                    elsif @boat[i] == @CANNIBAL_ID 

                        @cannibalsLeft+= 1
                end
                @boat[i]=@EMPTY_ID
            end
            @boatLocation = @SHORE_ID
    end

    return message
end


#build a string describing boat's occupants.
def getBoatOccupants  

    message = ""
    occupants = Array.new(2)


    #Get names for occupants
    i = 0
    for i in 0..2

        occupants[i] = ""
        if @boat[i] == @VEGAN_ID 
            occupants[i] = "vegan"
        end
        if @boat[i] == @CANNIBAL_ID 
            occupants[i] = "cannibal"
        end

    end
    #if boat is full start building string
    if @boat[1] != @EMPTY_ID 


        if @boat[0] == @boat[1] 

            message = "Two " + occupants[0]
            message +=  "s are "
        else

            message =  "One "+occupants[0]
            message += " and one " + occupants[1] + " are "
        end

    #if boat is empty start building string
        elsif @boat[1] == @EMPTY_ID 

            message = "One "+occupants[0]
            message +=  " is "
    end
    message +=  "in the boat "
    return message
end
def getBoatPosition  

    String location = ""
    if @boatLocation == @SHORE_ID 
        location = "at the starting position."
        elsif @boatLocation == @CROSSED_ID 
            location = "across the river."
    end
    return location
end


#/*Check to see if game is over and i programmed it wrong perfectGameLogic  or if user got eaten. */
def eaten  

    boolean gameOver = false

    if  @cannibalsLeft > @vegansLeft and @vegansLeft != 0  ||  @cannibalsCrossed > @vegansCrossed and @vegansCrossed != 0  
        gameOver = true
    return gameOver
end

#/*Used for gamLogic playable  only
# * decides if a users choice is valid given the circumstances.
# */
def isValid  

    validChoices = [true, true, true, true, true]
    if @boatLocation == @SHORE_ID 

        case @cannibalsLeft 

            when 0
                validChoices[0] = false
                validChoices[2] = false
                validChoices[3] = false
            when 1
                validChoices[0] = false
            else #//do nothing.
        end
        case @vegansLeft 

            when 0
                validChoices[1] = false
                validChoices[2] = false
                validChoices[4] = false
            when 1
                validChoices[1] = false
            else #//do nothing.
        end
        elsif @boatLocation == @CROSSED_ID 

            case @cannibalsCrossed 

                when 0
                    validChoices[0] = false
                    validChoices[2] = false
                    validChoices[3] = false
                when 1
                    validChoices[0] = false
                default:# //do nothing.
            end
            case @vegansCrossed 

                when 0
                    validChoices[1] = false
                    validChoices[2] = false
                    validChoices[4] = false
                when 1
                    validChoices[1] = false
                else #//do nothing.
            end
    end

    return validChoices
end
#/*This is for a preset game where rules are strict.
#no user input is required.
#game must move all cannibals across first,
#then 2 humans across
#then bring back one of each
#then save last human.
#base case: everyone crossed */
def self.perfectGameLogic (run) 

    message = ""

    if run == false 

        message = "Game Over"   
    else

        if  (@cannibalsLeft == 3 || @cannibalsLeft == 2  and @vegansLeft == 3) 

            message = message + populateBoat(0, @CROSSED_ID) 
            message +=unloadBoat(@CROSSED_ID) 
            message +=populateBoat(3, @SHORE_ID) 
            message +=unloadBoat(@SHORE_ID) 
            elsif @vegansLeft == 3 and @cannibalsLeft == 1 

                message +=populateBoat(1, @CROSSED_ID) 
                message +=unloadBoat(@CROSSED_ID) 
                message +=populateBoat(2, @SHORE_ID) 
                message +=unloadBoat(@SHORE_ID) 
            elsif @vegansLeft == 2 and @cannibalsLeft == 2 

                message +=populateBoat(1, @CROSSED_ID) 
                message +=unloadBoat(@CROSSED_ID) 
            elsif @vegansCrossed == 3 and @cannibalsCrossed < 3 
                i = 0
                for i in 0..2

                    message +=populateBoat(3, @SHORE_ID) 
                    message +=unloadBoat(@SHORE_ID) 
                    message +=populateBoat(0, @CROSSED_ID) 
                    message +=unloadBoat(@CROSSED_ID) 
                end
            elsif @vegansCrossed == 3 and @cannibalsCrossed == 3 

                message = "You Win!"
                run = false
        end
        puts message 
        if @eaten   == true 

            puts "you lose" 
            run = false
        end

            perfectGameLogic(run) 


    end
end
#/* this is a game the user gets to interact with.
# * if you get eaten, game is over, or if you win, game is over.
# */
def self.gameLogic(run) 

     message = ""
     error = ""
     choice
     destination = @CROSSED_ID
     choiceOk = false
    isValid = @isValid  


    if run == false 

        message = "Game Over"   
    else

        if @vegansCrossed == 3 and @cannibalsCrossed == 3 

            puts  "You Win!" 
            run = false
        else

            begin
                putsln error+"\n" 
                message = "The boat is " + @getBoatPosition   + "\n" +
                            @vegansCrossed+ " vegans have crossed and \n"+
                            @cannibalsCrossed + " cannibals have crossed. \n"
                            +"Please make a choice, who goes on the boat?: \n" +
                            "0 - load 2 cannibals \n" + 
                            "1 - load 2 vegans \n" +
                            "2 - load one of each \n" +
                            "3 - load 1 cannibal \n" +
                            "4 - load 1 Vegan \n" 
                puts message   
                choice = scan.nextInt  

                if choice < 5 and choice >= 0 

                    if isValid[choice] 

                        #//this is the only case where a choice is acceptable.
                        choiceOk = true
                    else

                        error = "You can't move people who aren't there."
                    end
                else

                    error= "You must choose a number between 0 and 4."
                end
            end
            end while choiceOk == false 

            if @boatLocation == @SHORE_ID 
                destination = @CROSSED_ID
                elsif @boatLocation == @CROSSED_ID 
                    destination = @SHORE_ID
                end
            end

            populateBoat(choice, destination) 
            unloadBoat(destination) 
        end
        if @eaten == true 

            puts "You Lose, those poor vegans! :  " 
            run = false
        end

        gameLogic run 


    end
end


end

Game = Cannibals.new
    #/#perfectGameLogic just runs.
    #//gameLogic is playable.
    #Game.perfectGameLogic(true);
    puts "***********************************Cannibals and vegan river crossing******************************** \n" +
                            "the object of the game is to get all the vegans across the river safetly. If the cannibals out number \n " +
                            "the vegans, they will be eaten alive and you lose the game, so try to avoid that!"
    Game.populateBoat(0,0)                  
    #Game.gameLogic(true)
```

this is my first attempt at ruby, previously this was coded in java so forgive me if i missed and java specific stuff in the code. And give me some pointers, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a class, a method declared using:

```
class MyClass
  def self.my_method
    # some stuff...
  end
end
```

Is a "class method". That means you can call it like so:

```
MyClass.my_method
```

It's also valid to have an "instance method" which is associated with a *member* of the class, not the class itself:

```
class MyClass
  def my_method
    # some stuff
  end
end
```

In your case, I think your code in "some other code in here........" may have a syntax error and an extra `end` statement, closing off the class too early and causing the `def self.gameLogic(...)` to be invalid since it's outside of the class.

There is a visible error in the logic in which you created a class method (as described above) with a `def self.gameLogic` but you're calling it as if it were an instance method with an instance of the class. You should call a class method as `Cannibals.gameLogic(...)`, or declare `gameLogic` as an instance method: `def gameLogic(...)` within the class.

Comment: I sorted out all of the sytax errors before getting to this point, but I will try to call a method earlier on in the code and see if i can find the extra end. Thank you.

Comment: I get the same error when trying to call the very first method in the class. no ends are before it, if i posted the entire code would it be helpful?

Comment: Without being able to see all the code, it's hard to come up with a further diagnosis. Is `gameLogic` intended to be recursive? From the code you show, it looks like it does call itself.

Comment: yes it's recursive, it was for an assignment which the professor specifically asked us to code it recursively. I'll post the full code now.

Comment: You are also calling it as if it were an instance class (you're calling it from the instance `Game`. You should either not create `Game` and just call it as a class method: `Cannibals.gameLogic(true)` or remove the `self.` from the front of the method declaration and call it the way you have it.

Comment: I can call the method without creating a Cannibals object? Sorry for the dumb questions but Ruby is very different for me. Used to php and Java- also the rest of the code is up.

Comment: Sure. Look up class methods versus insstance methods. The Class itself is an object, and instances of the class are objects in Ruby. In fact it's an error if you try to call a class method as if it were an instance method.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31016/discussion-between-bryan-and-mbratch)